# TLS on Windows Phone 7 - send client certificate in Bouncy Castle

Tags: security, ssl, windows-phone-7.1, bouncycastle, client-certificates

I have problem with sending client certificate to server on Window Phone 7 by using Bouncy Castle.

I created my own TlsAuthentication and TlsCredential class inherited from interfaces. But in method

```
public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest)
    {
        return this.TlsCredentials;
    }
```

an exception occurs.

Below is my exception:

```
An exception of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.TlsFatalAlert' occurred in bouncywp71.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in bouncywp71.DLL

An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in bouncywp71.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Internal TLS error, this could be an attack
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.TlsProtocolHandler.FailWithError(AlertLevel alertLevel, AlertDescription alertDescription)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.TlsProtocolHandler.SafeReadData()
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.TlsProtocolHandler.Connect(TlsClient tlsClient)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.Security.MyTestSecureClient.HandleConnectionReady()
at SocketEx.TcpClient.InnerConnect(EndPoint myEndpoint)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.Security.MyTestSecureClient..ctor(String host, Int32 port, TlsClient tlsClient)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.Security.MyTestSecureClient..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.ConnectionManager.CreateConnection(String host, Int32 port)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.ConnectionManager..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.MyTestService.CreateConnectionManager(String host, Int32 port)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Network.MyTestService.Login(LoginRequestModel request)
at MYAPP.MyTest2.ViewModel.LoginViewModel.<Login>b__1()
at MYAPP.MyTest2.Common.Helpers.ThreadHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3`1.<Execute>b__0(Object x)
```

If anyone know how to fix this, please help me !

Regards,
Artur